# CSS3: How to add more than 2 CSS Ribbon effects to same banner?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do you add 2 more CSS ribbons to the top of my banner? I have a JSFiddle demo set up here: **http://jsfiddle.net/jmxaZ/63/**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Nav menu here</p>
    <p>Nav menu here</p>
    <p>Nav menu here</p>    
</div>

<div class="banner-wrapper">        
    <div class="banner" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/850x300')">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p>Main content here</p>
    <p>Main content here</p>
    <p>Main content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is a CSS Ribbon?

Comment: Niels, it is the  black triangles you see on the jsfiddle example I posted. Here's more info: http://www.css3d.net/ribbon-generator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the pseudo elements to that:

CSS

```
.banner:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid black;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

This generates a trapezium instead of a triangle; but it gets hidden under the banner, and only the 2 triangles are shown

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmxaZ/64/)